# "Failed to load Azure Repos source specified by this pipeline" Error When another Project Administartor tries to run the Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I am running the pipeline there is no error that occurs.

But when another project administrator tries to Run a CI pipeline they get an "Failed to load Azure Repos source specified by this pipeline" Error.

Like below:

[image]

I assigned the other users as Project administrators and they too have the same permissions as me. Yet they get this error. How to mitigate this? Is it an organization-related setting or a project-related issue?

The users can still run the CI pipeline by clicking on the run button, just that they cannot select the "branch/tag" and this error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Failed to load Azure Repos source specified by this pipeline. Please ensure Azure Repos is enabled for this project.

The cause of the issue can be related to the Access Level of the users.

If the access level of the users are **Stakeholder**, they will have no access to the repos and get the error above even though they are Project admin.

Navigate to **Organization Settings -> Users** and check the Access Level of the users.

You need to grant **Basic** Access level to the users and they will have access to see the repo and select the branch when running Pipeline.

Refer to this doc: [About access levels in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops)